# SOLR convert string to date

Tags: solr

I have a dynamic field in SOLR that its value is stores as string
The value in it is a date string like:
 "md_LocalStartTime": "2013-01-31T22:12:54.8000000+0000",

I want to get the max value for this 
What wuery should I use to convert this to date and get the maximum?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, with this kind of date string representation lexical order is also date order, so ...sort=md_localStartTime%20DESC&rows=1&start=0